# Access information in a dictionary in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.x

I have a list of dictionaries called _deFV that look like this:

```
[{'indexID': 0, 'fv': [646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 644, 594, 788, 710, 632, 608, 780, 724, 615, 617, 770, 738, 614, 625, 776, 752, 623, 630, 793, 764, 598, 632, 783, 776, 555, 635, 762, 793], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 1, 'fv': [646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 644, 594, 788, 710, 632, 608, 780, 724, 1794, 634, 1857, 726, 1695, 626, 1759, 715, 1597, 622, 1653, 709, 1459, 616, 1509, 699, 1318, 604, 1368, 689], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 2, 'fv': [646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 644, 594, 788, 710, 632, 608, 780, 724, 1748, 625, 1781, 666, 1579, 609, 1606, 652, 1455, 596, 1479, 637, 1385, 585, 1410, 626, 1358, 576, 1384, 617], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 3, 'fv': [646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 644, 594, 788, 710, 632, 608, 780, 724, 1858, 627, 1878, 657, 1667, 612, 1684, 641, 1535, 597, 1549, 623, 1456, 584, 1464, 614, 1428, 574, 1437, 604], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 4, 'fv': [646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 644, 594, 788, 710, 632, 608, 780, 724, 1849, 624, 1886, 653, 1691, 606, 1723, 633, 1608, 590, 1637, 616, 1576, 576, 1604, 601, 1529, 572, 1556, 596], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 5, 'fv': [646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 644, 594, 788, 710, 632, 608, 780, 724, 1828, 623, 1852, 638, 1672, 605, 1693, 619, 1589, 590, 1608, 603, 1556, 576, 1575, 589, 1509, 572, 1527, 585], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 6, 'fv': [646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 644, 594, 788, 710, 632, 608, 780, 724, 1767, 625, 1804, 651, 1620, 609, 1653, 633, 1542, 594, 1573, 617, 1511, 582, 1542, 605, 1467, 578, 1496, 601], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 7, 'fv': [646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 646, 585, 789, 702, 644, 594, 788, 710, 632, 608, 780, 724, 1664, 603, 1673, 641, 1633, 587, 1645, 627, 1587, 583, 1602, 622, 1506, 581, 1521, 619, 1460, 574, 1474, 612], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 8, 'fv': [1772, 590, 1920, 692, 1772, 594, 1920, 697, 1813, 589, 1920, 690, 1836, 614, 1920, 688, 1909, 682, 1920, 714, 1861, 660, 1920, 732, 1884, 662, 1920, 725, 1885, 729, 1920, 814, 1695, 671, 1920, 845, 1506, 660, 1755, 826], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 9, 'fv': [1772, 590, 1920, 692, 1772, 594, 1920, 697, 1813, 589, 1920, 690, 1836, 614, 1920, 688, 1909, 682, 1920, 714, 1799, 635, 1846, 743, 1618, 635, 1658, 736, 1442, 625, 1475, 722, 1273, 610, 1304, 705, 1111, 595, 1144, 690], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 10, 'fv': [1217, 641, 1360, 870, 1237, 658, 1392, 926, 1300, 677, 1493, 981, 1401, 708, 1660, 1080, 1603, 741, 1920, 1080, 859, 562, 899, 593, 861, 557, 902, 588, 878, 551, 919, 582, 888, 549, 929, 580, 901, 550, 942, 582], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 11, 'fv': [962, 562, 986, 605, 926, 561, 950, 605, 885, 558, 911, 604, 857, 558, 884, 604, 824, 556, 849, 603, 791, 555, 818, 604, 767, 555, 796, 606, 767, 558, 796, 609, 764, 560, 793, 612, 768, 562, 797, 615], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 12, 'fv': [962, 562, 986, 605, 926, 561, 950, 605, 885, 558, 911, 604, 857, 558, 884, 604, 824, 556, 849, 603, 443, 593, 509, 710, 419, 603, 492, 729, 381, 606, 457, 739, 334, 613, 417, 754, 290, 614, 379, 766], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 13, 'fv': [962, 562, 986, 605, 926, 561, 950, 605, 885, 558, 911, 604, 857, 558, 884, 604, 824, 556, 849, 603, 1023, 552, 1049, 564, 1008, 552, 1038, 564, 1013, 551, 1044, 563, 1006, 550, 1036, 563, 982, 550, 1011, 562], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 14, 'fv': [570, 580, 621, 668, 545, 580, 597, 672, 538, 585, 592, 681, 532, 585, 589, 687, 521, 588, 581, 693, 443, 593, 509, 710, 419, 603, 492, 729, 381, 606, 457, 739, 334, 613, 417, 754, 290, 614, 379, 766], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 15, 'fv': [1664, 567, 1703, 632, 1674, 567, 1714, 633, 1684, 568, 1725, 633, 1694, 568, 1733, 633, 1703, 568, 1743, 633, 1712, 568, 1754, 633, 1723, 569, 1765, 633, 1731, 568, 1771, 633, 1741, 568, 1782, 633, 1750, 568, 1790, 633], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 16, 'fv': [696, 568, 726, 618, 704, 568, 734, 618, 696, 560, 724, 610, 690, 551, 719, 601, 683, 549, 713, 600, 691, 561, 720, 612, 700, 566, 730, 618, 704, 570, 735, 623, 686, 571, 716, 623, 686, 573, 716, 625], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 17, 'fv': [523, 564, 548, 622, 504, 562, 533, 621, 467, 558, 495, 620, 457, 563, 484, 626, 445, 564, 463, 626, 0, 704, 10, 735], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 18, 'fv': [796, 559, 831, 584, 799, 558, 834, 583, 801, 558, 837, 583, 812, 558, 848, 584, 826, 558, 862, 584, 832, 558, 869, 585, 840, 560, 876, 587, 844, 563, 881, 590, 846, 564, 884, 591, 839, 563, 877, 591], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 19, 'fv': [284, 613, 370, 644, 367, 600, 452, 630, 419, 590, 504, 620, 473, 591, 558, 621, 508, 591, 593, 621, 608, 589, 680, 616, 597, 600, 606, 617, 651, 584, 713, 611, 630, 593, 650, 613, 636, 583, 666, 608], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 20, 'fv': [284, 613, 370, 644, 367, 600, 452, 630, 419, 590, 504, 620, 473, 591, 558, 621, 508, 591, 593, 621, 216, 602, 310, 754, 179, 617, 281, 778, 129, 627, 240, 799, 51, 640, 175, 828, 0, 697, 14, 784], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 21, 'fv': [284, 613, 370, 644, 367, 600, 452, 630, 419, 590, 504, 620, 473, 591, 558, 621, 508, 591, 593, 621, 1017, 558, 1044, 587, 1045, 549, 1106, 586, 1050, 553, 1100, 590, 1009, 554, 1048, 591, 1054, 556, 1093, 594], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 22, 'fv': [604, 557, 642, 588, 598, 557, 606, 577, 566, 552, 597, 582, 554, 556, 569, 582, 564, 564, 572, 584, 216, 602, 310, 754, 179, 617, 281, 778, 129, 627, 240, 799, 51, 640, 175, 828, 0, 697, 14, 784], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 23, 'fv': [604, 557, 642, 588, 598, 557, 606, 577, 566, 552, 597, 582, 554, 556, 569, 582, 564, 564, 572, 584, 0, 704, 10, 735], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 24, 'fv': [801, 572, 857, 617, 799, 573, 855, 618, 797, 573, 854, 619, 794, 574, 853, 620, 792, 574, 852, 621, 789, 575, 850, 622, 786, 575, 848, 624, 783, 576, 846, 625, 779, 577, 844, 627, 775, 578, 842, 629], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 25, 'fv': [801, 572, 857, 617, 799, 573, 855, 618, 797, 573, 854, 619, 794, 574, 853, 620, 792, 574, 852, 621, 1458, 755, 1527, 958, 1458, 748, 1467, 766, 1341, 665, 1429, 791, 1351, 668, 1507, 985, 1369, 671, 1578, 1004], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 26, 'fv': [801, 572, 857, 617, 799, 573, 855, 618, 797, 573, 854, 619, 794, 574, 853, 620, 792, 574, 852, 621, 972, 549, 983, 571, 967, 549, 978, 571, 961, 548, 973, 571, 955, 549, 967, 571, 950, 549, 961, 571], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 27, 'fv': [801, 572, 857, 617, 799, 573, 855, 618, 797, 573, 854, 619, 794, 574, 853, 620, 792, 574, 852, 621, 904, 549, 916, 571, 899, 548, 910, 571, 892, 549, 904, 571, 887, 549, 899, 571, 881, 549, 893, 572], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 28, 'fv': [907, 565, 930, 576, 924, 565, 945, 576, 922, 565, 946, 576, 915, 565, 939, 576, 923, 565, 944, 576, 912, 562, 927, 573, 1887, 695, 1920, 773, 1701, 676, 1920, 799, 1512, 672, 1713, 789, 1336, 658, 1518, 774], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 29, 'fv': [907, 565, 930, 576, 924, 565, 945, 576, 922, 565, 946, 576, 915, 565, 939, 576, 923, 565, 944, 576, 848, 556, 861, 576, 861, 554, 874, 575, 868, 551, 881, 573, 880, 549, 893, 571, 888, 548, 901, 570], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 30, 'fv': [1277, 698, 1397, 1029, 1277, 730, 1388, 1080, 1297, 775, 1463, 1080, 1319, 831, 1508, 1080, 1476, 987, 1588, 1080, 922, 566, 949, 577, 914, 563, 941, 575, 892, 555, 923, 569, 893, 548, 924, 565, 899, 542, 931, 563], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 31, 'fv': [951, 558, 987, 575, 951, 556, 993, 573, 990, 554, 1009, 570, 966, 554, 989, 571, 990, 552, 1030, 569, 1012, 551, 1050, 568, 1051, 554, 1067, 567, 1023, 553, 1040, 568, 1059, 552, 1081, 567, 1048, 551, 1057, 566], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 32, 'fv': [447, 578, 461, 590, 472, 578, 498, 590, 481, 580, 507, 592, 478, 578, 500, 591, 487, 580, 503, 593, 523, 580, 548, 593, 526, 580, 551, 593, 503, 581, 520, 592, 511, 576, 537, 590, 483, 579, 506, 589], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 33, 'fv': [1476, 734, 1599, 1080, 1640, 791, 1874, 1080, 1011, 550, 1019, 574, 1004, 549, 1012, 573, 1000, 549, 1008, 573, 1001, 548, 1009, 572, 991, 548, 1000, 573, 994, 548, 1003, 573, 986, 549, 995, 575, 988, 552, 997, 579], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 34, 'fv': [1476, 734, 1599, 1080, 1640, 791, 1874, 1080, 1011, 550, 1019, 574, 1004, 549, 1012, 573, 1000, 549, 1008, 573, 1020, 558, 1040, 598, 1021, 557, 1043, 597, 1010, 556, 1032, 596, 1016, 554, 1040, 594, 1013, 554, 1036, 593], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 35, 'fv': [1476, 734, 1599, 1080, 1640, 791, 1874, 1080, 1011, 550, 1019, 574, 1004, 549, 1012, 573, 1000, 549, 1008, 573, 424, 551, 433, 577, 424, 547, 432, 573, 424, 549, 436, 574, 447, 531, 456, 557, 452, 538, 461, 564], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 36, 'fv': [1174, 591, 1211, 706, 1177, 593, 1213, 715, 1179, 595, 1220, 723, 1182, 599, 1226, 735, 1186, 603, 1231, 746, 1194, 613, 1242, 778, 1172, 617, 1225, 794, 1150, 623, 1207, 813, 1125, 630, 1188, 838, 1098, 638, 1161, 860], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 37, 'fv': [1174, 591, 1211, 706, 1177, 593, 1213, 715, 1179, 595, 1220, 723, 1182, 599, 1226, 735, 1186, 603, 1231, 746, 972, 549, 983, 571, 967, 549, 978, 571, 961, 548, 973, 571, 955, 549, 967, 571, 950, 549, 961, 571], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 38, 'fv': [1174, 591, 1211, 706, 1177, 593, 1213, 715, 1179, 595, 1220, 723, 1182, 599, 1226, 735, 1186, 603, 1231, 746, 904, 549, 916, 571, 899, 548, 910, 571, 892, 549, 904, 571, 887, 549, 899, 571, 881, 549, 893, 572], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 39, 'fv': [1192, 616, 1212, 711, 1230, 596, 1256, 726, 1230, 594, 1268, 718, 1243, 592, 1279, 709, 1254, 590, 1289, 703, 1263, 619, 1374, 813, 1247, 617, 1363, 800, 1240, 613, 1350, 791, 1230, 612, 1327, 786, 1230, 611, 1318, 776], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 40, 'fv': [1315, 813, 1689, 1080, 1366, 828, 1772, 1080, 1443, 958, 1658, 1080, 1445, 854, 1879, 1080, 1544, 1002, 1719, 1080, 1439, 589, 1469, 658, 1452, 587, 1473, 658, 1475, 593, 1491, 611, 1445, 591, 1478, 663, 1455, 586, 1497, 660], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 41, 'fv': [1315, 813, 1689, 1080, 1366, 828, 1772, 1080, 1443, 958, 1658, 1080, 1445, 854, 1879, 1080, 1544, 1002, 1719, 1080, 1833, 632, 1849, 646, 1591, 612, 1615, 623, 1434, 595, 1455, 606, 1210, 569, 1226, 583, 1135, 561, 1151, 574], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 42, 'fv': [442, 587, 504, 693, 409, 582, 476, 695, 357, 576, 429, 696, 314, 581, 393, 710, 296, 591, 378, 725, 216, 602, 310, 754, 179, 617, 281, 778, 129, 627, 240, 799, 51, 640, 175, 828, 0, 697, 14, 784], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 43, 'fv': [442, 587, 504, 693, 409, 582, 476, 695, 357, 576, 429, 696, 314, 581, 393, 710, 296, 591, 378, 725, 0, 704, 10, 735], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 44, 'fv': [179, 617, 281, 778, 129, 627, 240, 799, 51, 640, 175, 828, 0, 697, 14, 784, 0, 641, 74, 693, 0, 704, 10, 735], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 45, 'fv': [910, 591, 975, 727, 747, 584, 817, 726, 560, 576, 641, 730, 328, 562, 430, 735, 33, 548, 170, 750, 1786, 798, 1920, 1009, 1908, 1039, 1920, 1064, 1700, 779, 1920, 1080, 1613, 755, 1920, 1080, 1572, 742, 1920, 1080], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 46, 'fv': [1074, 560, 1118, 595, 1065, 557, 1122, 592, 1056, 550, 1126, 586, 1034, 548, 1113, 584, 1030, 548, 1103, 585, 1017, 558, 1044, 587, 1045, 549, 1106, 586, 1050, 553, 1100, 590, 1009, 554, 1048, 591, 1054, 556, 1093, 594], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 47, 'fv': [1074, 560, 1118, 595, 1065, 557, 1122, 592, 1056, 550, 1126, 586, 1034, 548, 1113, 584, 1030, 548, 1103, 585, 0, 704, 10, 735], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 48, 'fv': [1003, 559, 1016, 590, 1001, 563, 1016, 597, 1000, 564, 1015, 600, 1013, 562, 1031, 603, 1011, 561, 1030, 601, 1020, 558, 1040, 598, 1021, 557, 1043, 597, 1010, 556, 1032, 596, 1016, 554, 1040, 594, 1013, 554, 1036, 593], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 49, 'fv': [1003, 559, 1016, 590, 1001, 563, 1016, 597, 1000, 564, 1015, 600, 1013, 562, 1031, 603, 1011, 561, 1030, 601, 424, 551, 433, 577, 424, 547, 432, 573, 424, 549, 436, 574, 447, 531, 456, 557, 452, 538, 461, 564], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 50, 'fv': [1109, 560, 1139, 611, 1124, 560, 1156, 614, 1143, 561, 1174, 616, 1137, 562, 1172, 621, 1134, 566, 1170, 626, 1154, 574, 1194, 641, 1157, 578, 1198, 648, 1163, 579, 1206, 653, 1159, 581, 1208, 658, 1167, 580, 1214, 665], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 51, 'fv': [1109, 560, 1139, 611, 1124, 560, 1156, 614, 1143, 561, 1174, 616, 1137, 562, 1172, 621, 1134, 566, 1170, 626, 115, 562, 132, 593, 134, 564, 145, 593, 100, 563, 105, 599, 82, 560, 99, 594, 50, 562, 73, 602], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 52, 'fv': [1109, 560, 1139, 611, 1124, 560, 1156, 614, 1143, 561, 1174, 616, 1137, 562, 1172, 621, 1134, 566, 1170, 626, 424, 576, 460, 604, 396, 573, 438, 608, 362, 567, 396, 629, 332, 560, 361, 622, 307, 551, 335, 614], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 53, 'fv': [427, 552, 449, 574, 378, 552, 417, 574, 256, 532, 299, 554, 311, 533, 331, 556, 67, 502, 116, 528, 1835, 678, 1880, 776, 1639, 659, 1680, 751, 1492, 639, 1524, 728, 1397, 624, 1434, 712, 1329, 613, 1360, 704], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 54, 'fv': [427, 552, 449, 574, 378, 552, 417, 574, 256, 532, 299, 554, 311, 533, 331, 556, 67, 502, 116, 528, 1698, 633, 1727, 675, 1501, 614, 1526, 653, 1353, 595, 1376, 632, 1242, 581, 1264, 617, 1161, 570, 1180, 606], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 55, 'fv': [427, 552, 449, 574, 378, 552, 417, 574, 256, 532, 299, 554, 311, 533, 331, 556, 67, 502, 116, 528, 972, 549, 993, 557, 967, 541, 988, 549, 955, 536, 976, 544, 935, 534, 956, 542, 926, 535, 947, 544], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 56, 'fv': [803, 562, 839, 589, 803, 563, 839, 590, 816, 563, 853, 591, 824, 563, 862, 591, 842, 563, 880, 592, 859, 562, 899, 593, 861, 557, 902, 588, 878, 551, 919, 582, 888, 549, 929, 580, 901, 550, 942, 582], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 57, 'fv': [1260, 639, 1314, 847, 1294, 653, 1383, 897, 1365, 674, 1477, 968, 1497, 703, 1622, 1080, 1777, 753, 1920, 1080, 972, 549, 993, 557, 967, 541, 988, 549, 955, 536, 976, 544, 935, 534, 956, 542, 926, 535, 947, 544], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 58, 'fv': [1260, 639, 1314, 847, 1294, 653, 1383, 897, 1365, 674, 1477, 968, 1497, 703, 1622, 1080, 1777, 753, 1920, 1080, 666, 554, 682, 566, 650, 550, 674, 564, 640, 549, 672, 564, 623, 547, 664, 563, 621, 548, 644, 563], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 59, 'fv': [1260, 639, 1314, 847, 1294, 653, 1383, 897, 1365, 674, 1477, 968, 1497, 703, 1622, 1080, 1777, 753, 1920, 1080, 1035, 550, 1043, 574, 1029, 549, 1037, 573, 1017, 548, 1026, 572, 1011, 548, 1019, 572, 1020, 547, 1028, 571], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 60, 'fv': [1288, 658, 1413, 916, 1326, 664, 1437, 939, 1279, 677, 1305, 734, 1377, 681, 1467, 948, 1308, 676, 1353, 748, 1458, 755, 1527, 958, 1458, 748, 1467, 766, 1341, 665, 1429, 791, 1351, 668, 1507, 985, 1369, 671, 1578, 1004], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 61, 'fv': [1288, 658, 1413, 916, 1326, 664, 1437, 939, 1279, 677, 1305, 734, 1377, 681, 1467, 948, 1308, 676, 1353, 748, 1069, 554, 1081, 583, 1066, 554, 1082, 584, 1062, 554, 1077, 577, 1047, 554, 1056, 577, 1038, 551, 1052, 581], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 62, 'fv': [1389, 638, 1542, 883, 1355, 635, 1497, 872, 1339, 634, 1484, 862, 1320, 627, 1447, 844, 1292, 625, 1422, 828, 1263, 619, 1374, 813, 1247, 617, 1363, 800, 1240, 613, 1350, 791, 1230, 612, 1327, 786, 1230, 611, 1318, 776], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 63, 'fv': [1389, 638, 1542, 883, 1355, 635, 1497, 872, 1339, 634, 1484, 862, 1320, 627, 1447, 844, 1292, 625, 1422, 828, 11, 605, 58, 710, 29, 602, 81, 709, 54, 607, 92, 676, 72, 677, 88, 716, 51, 677, 72, 716], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 64, 'fv': [1575, 561, 1587, 574, 1624, 548, 1647, 562, 1599, 554, 1620, 567, 1582, 554, 1602, 566, 1551, 559, 1568, 570, 151, 561, 178, 586, 95, 549, 123, 577, 0, 534, 7, 570, 11, 567, 32, 582, 11, 568, 39, 612], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 65, 'fv': [1575, 561, 1587, 574, 1624, 548, 1647, 562, 1599, 554, 1620, 567, 1582, 554, 1602, 566, 1551, 559, 1568, 570, 582, 561, 598, 608, 614, 568, 624, 616, 644, 568, 652, 616, 606, 563, 622, 613, 551, 556, 569, 608], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 66, 'fv': [1312, 806, 1510, 1080, 1294, 855, 1482, 1080, 1262, 888, 1442, 1080, 1205, 949, 1350, 1080, 1154, 1065, 1207, 1080, 641, 560, 678, 618, 629, 563, 664, 624, 631, 569, 670, 633, 644, 576, 684, 641, 652, 580, 690, 648], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 67, 'fv': [938, 549, 950, 571, 927, 549, 938, 571, 921, 549, 932, 571, 916, 548, 927, 571, 910, 549, 921, 571, 904, 549, 916, 571, 899, 548, 910, 571, 892, 549, 904, 571, 887, 549, 899, 571, 881, 549, 893, 572], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 68, 'fv': [938, 549, 950, 571, 927, 549, 938, 571, 921, 549, 932, 571, 916, 548, 927, 571, 910, 549, 921, 571, 1069, 554, 1081, 583, 1066, 554, 1082, 584, 1062, 554, 1077, 577, 1047, 554, 1056, 577, 1038, 551, 1052, 581], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 69, 'fv': [333, 554, 356, 589, 302, 548, 328, 583, 225, 536, 249, 573, 129, 530, 158, 569, 93, 542, 121, 581, 115, 562, 132, 593, 134, 564, 145, 593, 100, 563, 105, 599, 82, 560, 99, 594, 50, 562, 73, 602], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 70, 'fv': [333, 554, 356, 589, 302, 548, 328, 583, 225, 536, 249, 573, 129, 530, 158, 569, 93, 542, 121, 581, 424, 576, 460, 604, 396, 573, 438, 608, 362, 567, 396, 629, 332, 560, 361, 622, 307, 551, 335, 614], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 71, 'fv': [69, 571, 100, 611, 40, 562, 72, 602, 31, 565, 66, 605, 36, 564, 65, 606, 11, 558, 42, 599, 424, 576, 460, 604, 396, 573, 438, 608, 362, 567, 396, 629, 332, 560, 361, 622, 307, 551, 335, 614], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 72, 'fv': [473, 561, 500, 579, 464, 567, 476, 580, 481, 568, 497, 586, 456, 570, 478, 587, 435, 571, 466, 597, 424, 576, 460, 604, 396, 573, 438, 608, 362, 567, 396, 629, 332, 560, 361, 622, 307, 551, 335, 614], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 73, 'fv': [1122, 552, 1134, 580, 1122, 550, 1130, 576, 1128, 547, 1140, 575, 1119, 549, 1125, 576, 1070, 550, 1079, 577, 966, 548, 980, 576, 926, 547, 942, 575, 902, 548, 917, 577, 877, 551, 895, 580, 859, 552, 874, 571], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 74, 'fv': [1122, 552, 1134, 580, 1122, 550, 1130, 576, 1128, 547, 1140, 575, 1119, 549, 1125, 576, 1070, 550, 1079, 577, 752, 542, 769, 572, 721, 542, 736, 572, 700, 546, 716, 576, 677, 548, 694, 579, 659, 550, 678, 582], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 75, 'fv': [1122, 552, 1134, 580, 1122, 550, 1130, 576, 1128, 547, 1140, 575, 1119, 549, 1125, 576, 1070, 550, 1079, 577, 619, 550, 638, 582, 580, 546, 600, 580, 556, 548, 578, 582, 524, 545, 546, 580, 459, 537, 482, 573], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 76, 'fv': [202, 584, 247, 709, 147, 581, 197, 710, 62, 578, 118, 714, 22, 588, 80, 729, 0, 605, 13, 693, 647, 534, 654, 561, 527, 518, 542, 546, 365, 496, 382, 526, 150, 471, 171, 490, 1087, 546, 1097, 566], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 77, 'fv': [202, 584, 247, 709, 147, 581, 197, 710, 62, 578, 118, 714, 22, 588, 80, 729, 0, 605, 13, 693, 1900, 580, 1920, 632, 1858, 582, 1900, 634, 1842, 579, 1882, 633, 1827, 579, 1846, 633, 1852, 583, 1869, 599], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 78, 'fv': [709, 557, 738, 606, 693, 558, 722, 608, 694, 560, 726, 612, 681, 558, 712, 613, 659, 558, 693, 615, 641, 560, 678, 618, 629, 563, 664, 624, 631, 569, 670, 633, 644, 576, 684, 641, 652, 580, 690, 648], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 79, 'fv': [709, 557, 738, 606, 693, 558, 722, 608, 694, 560, 726, 612, 681, 558, 712, 613, 659, 558, 693, 615, 530, 583, 592, 691, 503, 586, 575, 704, 476, 591, 554, 716, 453, 600, 534, 740, 417, 607, 511, 763], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 80, 'fv': [649, 577, 693, 652, 639, 578, 684, 656, 637, 579, 687, 662, 621, 577, 670, 666, 595, 578, 650, 672, 530, 583, 592, 691, 503, 586, 575, 704, 476, 591, 554, 716, 453, 600, 534, 740, 417, 607, 511, 763], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 81, 'fv': [1228, 563, 1244, 586, 1246, 563, 1255, 608, 1231, 565, 1242, 611, 1216, 565, 1229, 588, 1223, 564, 1234, 611, 1239, 560, 1249, 605, 1218, 562, 1232, 577, 1234, 562, 1247, 609, 1220, 563, 1232, 577, 1237, 562, 1251, 611], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 82, 'fv': [1228, 563, 1244, 586, 1246, 563, 1255, 608, 1231, 565, 1242, 611, 1216, 565, 1229, 588, 1223, 564, 1234, 611, 1825, 540, 1867, 608, 1855, 534, 1893, 602, 1875, 534, 1898, 552, 1708, 622, 1732, 656, 1537, 606, 1557, 639], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 83, 'fv': [1643, 565, 1680, 628, 1664, 571, 1702, 633, 1702, 566, 1730, 631, 1793, 550, 1803, 565, 1796, 567, 1803, 608, 1825, 540, 1867, 608, 1855, 534, 1893, 602, 1875, 534, 1898, 552, 1708, 622, 1732, 656, 1537, 606, 1557, 639], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 84, 'fv': [995, 550, 1008, 572, 974, 554, 988, 576, 976, 555, 990, 577, 988, 554, 1001, 576, 1005, 552, 1019, 574, 1020, 550, 1033, 572, 1027, 548, 1039, 569, 1019, 547, 1033, 570, 1004, 547, 1018, 569, 990, 546, 1003, 567], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 85, 'fv': [995, 550, 1008, 572, 974, 554, 988, 576, 976, 555, 990, 577, 988, 554, 1001, 576, 1005, 552, 1019, 574, 899, 549, 911, 572, 893, 552, 905, 575, 888, 555, 900, 579, 886, 560, 897, 583, 881, 567, 893, 587], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 86, 'fv': [995, 550, 1008, 572, 974, 554, 988, 576, 976, 555, 990, 577, 988, 554, 1001, 576, 1005, 552, 1019, 574, 752, 542, 769, 572, 721, 542, 736, 572, 700, 546, 716, 576, 677, 548, 694, 579, 659, 550, 678, 582], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 87, 'fv': [937, 536, 949, 559, 931, 540, 942, 563, 924, 544, 935, 566, 918, 546, 929, 569, 912, 547, 923, 570, 899, 549, 911, 572, 893, 552, 905, 575, 888, 555, 900, 579, 886, 560, 897, 583, 881, 567, 893, 587], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 88, 'fv': [937, 536, 949, 559, 931, 540, 942, 563, 924, 544, 935, 566, 918, 546, 929, 569, 912, 547, 923, 570, 752, 542, 769, 572, 721, 542, 736, 572, 700, 546, 716, 576, 677, 548, 694, 579, 659, 550, 678, 582], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 89, 'fv': [937, 536, 949, 559, 931, 540, 942, 563, 924, 544, 935, 566, 918, 546, 929, 569, 912, 547, 923, 570, 619, 550, 638, 582, 580, 546, 600, 580, 556, 548, 578, 582, 524, 545, 546, 580, 459, 537, 482, 573], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 90, 'fv': [562, 573, 574, 593, 551, 576, 560, 602, 609, 569, 630, 609, 656, 565, 677, 605, 669, 560, 693, 592, 695, 559, 716, 589, 732, 559, 754, 592, 764, 559, 788, 599, 784, 558, 806, 600, 799, 561, 822, 603], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 91, 'fv': [562, 573, 574, 593, 551, 576, 560, 602, 609, 569, 630, 609, 656, 565, 677, 605, 669, 560, 693, 592, 1066, 564, 1093, 615, 1093, 565, 1114, 617, 1091, 565, 1115, 620, 1086, 565, 1112, 621, 1073, 565, 1102, 622], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 92, 'fv': [1024, 557, 1048, 604, 1020, 559, 1046, 606, 1010, 559, 1035, 607, 1011, 559, 1037, 608, 1034, 559, 1059, 608, 1066, 564, 1093, 615, 1093, 565, 1114, 617, 1091, 565, 1115, 620, 1086, 565, 1112, 621, 1073, 565, 1102, 622], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 93, 'fv': [1024, 557, 1048, 604, 1020, 559, 1046, 606, 1010, 559, 1035, 607, 1011, 559, 1037, 608, 1034, 559, 1059, 608, 1799, 635, 1846, 743, 1618, 635, 1658, 736, 1442, 625, 1475, 722, 1273, 610, 1304, 705, 1111, 595, 1144, 690], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 94, 'fv': [1659, 557, 1674, 580, 1625, 556, 1639, 581, 1543, 556, 1554, 581, 1536, 556, 1549, 579, 1490, 557, 1503, 575, 151, 561, 178, 586, 95, 549, 123, 577, 0, 534, 7, 570, 11, 567, 32, 582, 11, 568, 39, 612], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 95, 'fv': [1659, 557, 1674, 580, 1625, 556, 1639, 581, 1543, 556, 1554, 581, 1536, 556, 1549, 579, 1490, 557, 1503, 575, 582, 561, 598, 608, 614, 568, 624, 616, 644, 568, 652, 616, 606, 563, 622, 613, 551, 556, 569, 608], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 96, 'fv': [883, 553, 897, 579, 879, 551, 892, 578, 889, 549, 906, 576, 851, 549, 867, 574, 793, 542, 810, 571, 752, 542, 769, 572, 721, 542, 736, 572, 700, 546, 716, 576, 677, 548, 694, 579, 659, 550, 678, 582], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 97, 'fv': [883, 553, 897, 579, 879, 551, 892, 578, 889, 549, 906, 576, 851, 549, 867, 574, 793, 542, 810, 571, 619, 550, 638, 582, 580, 546, 600, 580, 556, 548, 578, 582, 524, 545, 546, 580, 459, 537, 482, 573], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 98, 'fv': [752, 542, 769, 572, 721, 542, 736, 572, 700, 546, 716, 576, 677, 548, 694, 579, 659, 550, 678, 582, 619, 550, 638, 582, 580, 546, 600, 580, 556, 548, 578, 582, 524, 545, 546, 580, 459, 537, 482, 573], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 99, 'fv': [80, 589, 96, 611, 105, 588, 150, 682, 76, 588, 108, 657, 23, 584, 66, 631, 78, 659, 89, 681, 1799, 635, 1846, 743, 1618, 635, 1658, 736, 1442, 625, 1475, 722, 1273, 610, 1304, 705, 1111, 595, 1144, 690], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 100, 'fv': [238, 526, 261, 542, 159, 525, 185, 542, 101, 529, 129, 551, 84, 541, 113, 564, 124, 559, 151, 583, 151, 561, 178, 586, 95, 549, 123, 577, 0, 534, 7, 570, 11, 567, 32, 582, 11, 568, 39, 612], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 101, 'fv': [165, 566, 185, 597, 165, 567, 188, 629, 165, 567, 197, 629, 165, 569, 204, 629, 178, 573, 207, 629, 213, 567, 233, 586, 213, 567, 241, 629, 193, 585, 207, 609, 213, 567, 249, 629, 217, 567, 257, 629], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 102, 'fv': [165, 566, 185, 597, 165, 567, 188, 629, 165, 567, 197, 629, 165, 569, 204, 629, 178, 573, 207, 629, 1811, 666, 1827, 682, 1856, 660, 1883, 679, 1814, 701, 1830, 745, 1861, 696, 1880, 755, 1868, 619, 1881, 691], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 103, 'fv': [227, 579, 292, 664, 191, 574, 256, 664, 134, 566, 198, 660, 37, 557, 114, 658, 0, 563, 44, 614, 1811, 666, 1827, 682, 1856, 660, 1883, 679, 1814, 701, 1830, 745, 1861, 696, 1880, 755, 1868, 619, 1881, 691], 'out': 1}, {'indexID': 104, 'fv': [1011, 568, 1028, 630, 1016, 568, 1042, 630, 1032, 568, 1049, 630, 1039, 568, 1064, 630, 1051, 568, 1070, 630, 1061, 568, 1084, 630, 1070, 568, 1091, 630, 1083, 568, 1106, 630, 1090, 568, 1115, 630, 1105, 568, 1122, 630], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 105, 'fv': [1011, 568, 1028, 630, 1016, 568, 1042, 630, 1032, 568, 1049, 630, 1039, 568, 1064, 630, 1051, 568, 1070, 630, 1811, 666, 1827, 682, 1856, 660, 1883, 679, 1814, 701, 1830, 745, 1861, 696, 1880, 755, 1868, 619, 1881, 691], 'out': 0}, {'indexID': 106, 'fv': [1704, 690, 1723, 725, 1743, 655, 1762, 671, 1718, 645, 1724, 671, 1746, 660, 1761, 702, 1780, 651, 1804, 672, 1811, 666, 1827, 682, 1856, 660, 1883, 679, 1814, 701, 1830, 745, 1861, 696, 1880, 755, 1868, 619, 1881, 691], 'out': 0}]
```

I want to count the number of values in the 'fv' for each indexID and identify (print out) and later remove the indexIDs that has number of values in the 'fv' that is not equal to 40. How can I do this?

I know how to access the values of a dictionary but I do not know how to access the dictionary values in the list.

**UPDATE**

```
not_40 = [d for d in _deFV if len(d['fv']) != 40]
remove_list = []
pos = 0

for x in not_40:
    print "\nThese entries in _deFV will be removed as they do not have 40 features in the feature vetor: \n{}".format(x)
    remove_list.append(int(x['indexID']))

for dic in _deFV:
    if dic['indexID'] == remove_list[pos]:
        pos+=1
```

I can identify which dictionay in the list I want to remove but I am not sure how to do so. However, I do get this error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the elements in your data that do not have a length of 40 like this:

#### Code:

```
not_40 = [d for d in data if len(d['fv']) != 40]
```

#### Test Code:

```
for x in not_40:
    print(x)
```

#### Results:

```
{'indexID': 17, 'fv': [523, 564, 548, 622, 504, 562, 533, 621, 467, 558, 495, 620, 457, 563, 484, 626, 445, 564, 463, 626, 0, 704, 10, 735], 'out': 1}
{'indexID': 23, 'fv': [604, 557, 642, 588, 598, 557, 606, 577, 566, 552, 597, 582, 554, 556, 569, 582, 564, 564, 572, 584, 0, 704, 10, 735], 'out': 1}
{'indexID': 43, 'fv': [442, 587, 504, 693, 409, 582, 476, 695, 357, 576, 429, 696, 314, 581, 393, 710, 296, 591, 378, 725, 0, 704, 10, 735], 'out': 1}
{'indexID': 44, 'fv': [179, 617, 281, 778, 129, 627, 240, 799, 51, 640, 175, 828, 0, 697, 14, 784, 0, 641, 74, 693, 0, 704, 10, 735], 'out': 1}
{'indexID': 47, 'fv': [1074, 560, 1118, 595, 1065, 557, 1122, 592, 1056, 550, 1126, 586, 1034, 548, 1113, 584, 1030, 548, 1103, 585, 0, 704, 10, 735], 'out': 1}
```

Comment: And if I wanted to remove that particular dictionary from the list, can I use data.pop(x) inside the for loop?

Comment: `pop` removes the item from the list and returns the item. If you want to just remove, use `remove`

Comment: @bunbun thanks! I am not sure why someone down voted it as this code works for me but it is not yet complete. I realized that removing from not_40 is not what I need as I need to remove that entry from the original _deFV. Is there another list comprehension for this?

Comment: generally we dont advocate modifying a list while iterating through it. Hence, you can just do `_deFV = not_40`

Comment: @bunbun oh what I meant was that instead of creating a new list of dictionaries that contains all the dictionaries I want to remove, I would like to simply remove them from the original list of dictionaries. Is this possible?